# Angular: update scope inside scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

I have a controller with 2 scopes:

```
app.controller('search', function($scope) {
    $scope.value1 = '';
    $scope.value2 = 'Some text' + $scope.value1;
}
```

And an input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value1">
```

When I change value1 with the input field (which works), value2 doesn't get updated. How can I make this work?

Comment: Only objects are pass by reference in JS - not primitives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could follow dot rule while declaring object. That will give you [**prototypal inheritance**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) thing. Both `param1` & `param2` will refer to the same copy of object. So that updating one would update the other one automatically.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="param1.value">
<input type="text" ng-model="param2.value">
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('search', function($scope) {
    $scope.param1 = {value : ''};
    $scope.param2 = $scope.param1;
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0YmAJwZe2CsHa8IIZKLP?p=preview)

**Update**

If you wanted to keep those variable as primitive then you should have to update them on some event like here you could do it by using `ng-change` directive

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value1" ng-change="value2 = value1 + ' something'">
```

Or simply you can move inline html code to you controller function to make it testable.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value1" ng-change="changedValue()">
```

**Code**

```
$scope.changedValue = function(){
    $scope.value2 = $scope.value1 + ' something' 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pankaj! I forgot to mention that the 2 scopes shouldn't be exactly the same. I've edited my question. When I change this in your example it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jarno does both of them are used as input element?

Comment: No only value1 is linked to an input.

Comment: @Jarno Glad to help you..Thnaks :)